# What is this plant with arrowhead shaped leaves with black splotches?

Tags: identification, weeds

I have noticed this plant growing near my fruit bushes and it is spreading. Its leaves are shaped like arrowheads and have black splotches on them.

Is it a weed or friendly plant?

[image]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Arum maculatum - this plant sometimes has these black markings on the leaves, sometimes doesn't, but either way, the berries it produces in autumn (fall) are highly toxic. There aren't many cases of poisoning from it though because they burn the mouth so people spit them out if they try them. The sap can be extremely irritant to the skin, and all parts are toxic, but this plant occurs in the wild and in less cultivated parts of gardens all the time, and is classed as a 'wildflower'. Common names in the UK include Cuckoo Pint as well as Lords and Ladies.

More info here if you're interested

https://easywildflowers.wordpress.com/about/green-wildflowers-of-the-uk/arum-maculatum-the-wild-arum/

Comment: Both the spadix and the fruits are beautiful. Fruits in autumn? I was thinking much earlier.

Comment: Not really - can be found end of August sometimes, usually early September, so that's autumn, albeit early autumn.